# Is it possible to get the host computer docker IP from within a docker?

Tags: docker

I'm wanting to make a connection back to the email server on the host computer from within the docker.  Right now, I can do ifconfig and get the ip from the docker0 device, but that requires manual intervention to set the IP within the docker.  And if the docker image is saved and copied to a new server, that IP might not be the same.

Is there some way to get the internal host IP (from docker0) from within the docker at runtime (maybe from the environment)?

At the moment I don't see it as part of the environment, so I'm wondering if I have to something during docker setup to enable it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to get the address from the host, why not run dhcp inside the container ? e.g. add

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

inside /etc/network/interfaces and then do /etc/init.d/network restart

Comment: I'm trying to get the IP of the host, not the docker.  How would changing it to dhcp accomplisth that?

Comment: Does run --env <key>=<value> work ? I guess not as it changes often. Or try "/sbin/ip route|awk '/default/ { print $3 }'" to get the default route (hopefully the host)

Comment: It's sounding more and more like finding that address is not going to be easy..

Comment: /sbin/ip route|awk '/default/ { print $3 }' | head -1  - worked for me and it has the advantage that it will work with and without a host container. It's just getting your default route which should be the host...

Comment: That did it.  Don't know why that didn't occur to me.  Thanks.